# Enviar arquivo C# API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma aplicação MVC em C#, que é um sistema WEb. E tenho uma API em C# que recebe as chamadas do Site. Estou precisando enviar um arquivo do Site para a API, fiz o código da seguinte forma:

**Código do Site enviando para o controller da API**

```
public TRetorno Post<TEnvio, TRetorno>(TEnvio data, Stream arquivo)
    {
        using (var httpClient = this.CriarClient())
        {
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(this.endpoint)
            };

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            content.Add(new StreamContent(arquivo), "file", "filename");                
            content.Add(new ObjectContent<TEnvio>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()), "model");

            httpRequest.Content = content;

            using (var response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).Result)
            {
                this.AplicarTratamentoDeRetorno(response);

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TRetorno>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Código do Controlador da API

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("IncluirArquivos")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostArquivos(ImportacaoCredoresModel model)
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

        servicoDeAplicacaoDeImportacao.IncluirArquivoImportacao(model.CodigoCredor, file.InputStream, model.NomeArquivo);
        var arquivos = servicoDeAplicacaoDeRecuperacaoDeImportacoes.ConsultarArquivosImportacao(model.CodigoCredor);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ConversoesImportacao.ConverterEmArquivos(arquivos));
    }
```

O problema é que ao pegar o parâmetro `var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];` ele está `null`.

Eu coloquei em outro PC o mesmo código e o parâmetro não vem `null`, vem preenchido com o arquivo? Poder ser alguma configuração do IIS? Versão do FrameWork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, resolvi meu problema atualizando o Framework .Net4.5.